# Is paypal's IPN reliable enough?

Tags: paypal

I am creating my first ever major plugin for Wordpress and I intend to share it to the community. It integrates paypal's subscription button which is very useful for people who wishe to build a membership site using Wordpress. Question: Is IPN reliable enough that there's no need to control the subscription thru cron myself? I have not tested my plugin for a span of a month or so though because doing so would eat a lot of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is reliable enough. Thousands of businesses depend on it and it just doesn't fail. Now, is the plug in reliable? That's something you need to research more.

Comment: Yah, admittedly I am not sure if my plugin is reliable. It's something I hope the community can help about. :-)

Comment: Whomever downvoted this want to explain why?

Answer (score 3):

I've never had any problems with it, and I've used it on a few sites before. So I'd say yeah, it's pretty reliable.